# lightgbm<=3.3.1: early_stopping() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_delta'

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, lightgbm

I am dealing with a Regression problem for which I used `LGBMRegressor`. I also utilize `early_stopping` as callback in `.fit(...)` as follows:

```
reg = LGBMRegressor(**lgbr_params)
reg.fit(train_valid[features], 
        train_valid[target], 
        verbose=100,
        eval_set=[(test[features], test[target])], 
                   eval_metric=['rmse', 'mae'],
                   callbacks=[early_stopping(stopping_rounds=10, first_metric_only=False)], )
```

which works quite fine. However, I would like to consider some sort of "tolerance" in my `early_stopping` callback function. According to [lightgbm documentation](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pythonapi/lightgbm.early_stopping.html), this is apparently possible using `min_delta` argument in early stopping callback function.
When I add this to my code:

```
reg = LGBMRegressor(**lgbr_params)
reg.fit(train_valid[features], 
        train_valid[target], 
        verbose=100,
        eval_set=[(test[features], test[target])], 
                   eval_metric=['rmse', 'mae'],
                   callbacks=[early_stopping(stopping_rounds=10, first_metric_only=False), min_delta=[0.1, 0.1]])
```

I face with the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-834c9eaac9b2> in <module>
      1 reg = LGBMRegressor(**lgbr_params)
      2 reg.fit(train_valid[features], train_valid[target], eval_set=[(test[features], test[target])], eval_metric=['rmse'],
----> 3         callbacks=[early_stopping(stopping_rounds=10, first_metric_only=False, min_delta=[1.0])], verbose=100)
TypeError: early_stopping() got an unexpected keyword argument 'min_delta'
```

I am using windows, and tried to upgrade the lightbm to solve the issue, but failed.
Any idea?

Comment: You failed to upgrade lightgbm, or the upgrade failed to solve the issue? And what is your lightgbm version?

Comment: The documentation you link to is for the latest bleeding edge version of LightGBM, where apparently the argument became available for the first time; it is not included in the latest stable version [3.3.1](https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM/releases) (check the respective [docs](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/v3.3.1/pythonapi/lightgbm.early_stopping.html)).

Comment: @desertnaut: Seems your are right. I need to wait for it ...

Comment: This error still happens with lightgbm 3.3.3 (Released: Oct 10, 2022)

Answer (score 3):

I was facing the same issue, as latest lightgbm release on pipy is 3.3.1, I had to install it from github.

1. First install [cmake](https://cmake.org/)
2. Install [lightgbm from github](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Installation-Guide.html#build-from-github)

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/microsoft/LightGBM
cd LightGBM/python-package
python setup.py install
```

it shoud work now

```
from lightgbm import early_stopping

early_stopping(stopping_rounds=10, first_metric_only=False, min_delta=[0.1, 0.1])
>>> <function lightgbm.callback.early_stopping.<locals>._callback(env: lightgbm.callback.CallbackEnv) -> None>
```